# VBA Excel Random 'divisible by zero' errors

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I have a VBA Userform that calculates a freight quote that is rather long and complicated. When i run the macro that calculates the quote I keep getting

> Run Time error 11: 'Divisible By Zero'

on random lines. I debug and the line the error is referring to is something like:

```
If TQM < Cbox.Cells(3, 1) Then
```

or

```
TQ1 = Q1.Value
```

where

```
Dim TQM, TQ1 as Double
dim Q1 as Control 'refers to Combobox on form. Value in Q1 must be number,
                  'this is checked earlier in sub, cannot reach this point otherwise
```

Without making changes, I click resume and the sub continues as if there was no error at all. Is this a problem with excel vba on OS x? Is there some way of fixing this issue without going through each potential point of error (which could be many) and putting in an On error statement?

Comment: Have you checked in a debugger to see if there actually *are* divisions by zero?  It's possible that when the debugger asserts that it's just highlighting the wrong line of code.

Comment: I'm not sure, but give this a try: `If CDbl(Val(TQM)) < CDbl(Val(Cbox.Cells(3, 1))) Then` and `TQ1 = CDbl(Val(Q1.Value))`.

Comment: There is no dividing throughout the whole sub, so there should be no divisions by zero anywhere @Comintern.

Comment: I was trying to avoid going through and adjusting every line of code if i can @Fadi. I even got a divisible by zero error on    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = TotBox

Comment: @KidButters, I faced similar problems a few years ago when I design my workbook in windows 8 and it worked without problems at all , but when tried to use this workbook on windows 7 these errors appeared. and every time the error message popup I go to the vba line and change it to CDbl , Cstr , etc, and now it works fine on both windows, but really didn't know why this errors in windows 7 , so i posted my comment maybe can help. so sorry about that.

Comment: In my experience , an integer overflow causes mayhem and code execution jumps to random lines in the code - check the locals window as you step through the code and watch out for integers , change to long

Comment: I should say a variable overflow- it doesn't need to be only an integer that's out of bounds